Direct connection to Hbase storage in Apache Atlas
How to directly connect to the HBase storage in Apache Atlas for audit logs?
I'm trying to understand how to establish a direct connection to the HBase storage in Apache Atlas. The audit logs in the Apache Atlas interface are distributed between entities and a system log of certain events (such as server restart, type creation, etc.). Through the Apache Atlas Rest API, access is limited to the audit log of a specific entity. However, I would like to have access to a comprehensive audit log of all events, for example, for the current day. Since HBase is the data store for Apache Atlas, which was installed along with Apache Atlas, I need direct access to HBase in order to search for the necessary information there.
I attempted to retrieve information by sending requests like:
curl http://localhost:/master-status?name=apache_atlas_entity_audit
However, they return general information about the state of the HBase database. I would like to get information from the apache_atlas_entity_audit table.
